# Creating a constraint or key with Entity Framework Code First to ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, asp.net-identity

I have the ApplicationUser class with more data added here

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime MembershipCreated { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; } 
}
```

And I have another class 'Space' that I want to connect to ApplicationUser's id so that if I try and delete the ApplicationUser entry and there is a 'Space' entry that is assocaited with the ApplicationUser entry I get an error because of a key or constraint or something.

What do I do to accomplish this?

```
public class Space
{
    public int SpaceId { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = false)]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string AspNetUserRefId { get; set; }

  //other members here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have somethink like this in your space class

```
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
public int ApplicationUserID {get; set;}
```

Comment: you need to make sure both class name is right  are same and it  and property is in Space

Comment: I tried this and received this error message when updating the database. "The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ApplicationUserId' on type 'project.DomainClasses.Models.MySpace.Space'is not valid. The navigation property 'ApplicationUser' was not found on the dependent type 'project.DomainClasses.Models.MySpace.Space'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name."

Comment: can you please further explain? I'm not understanding what you are saying. What class name needs to be "right" and what property should be in Space?

Comment: How is it that you are assigning "ApplicationUser" . This is not a key ... is it?

Comment: It a class/table that he is referncing

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, but now I'm having problems assigning a value to the foreign key

I added

```
[Required]
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

to the 'Space' entity.
So now I see a column called ApplicationUser_Id that's a nvarchar(128)

But now I'm having a problem assigning my id to this field when I create a new 'Space' entity because I'm trying to assign a string to applicationuser which is a type applicationuser and not a string. I want to store a string id in the field.

Answer (score 0):

create Foreign Key as below

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // other properties

    public virtual ICollection<Space> Space { get;set;}
}

public class Space
{
    // other properties

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```